# How can I select something from a listbox

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to read the string that is in a listbox item, prompt the user to enter the string, and if the user enters it in correctly SELECT the next item until there are no items left to select?  I am making this in VB.NET. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To hopefully clear it up, there are 3 items in a listbox. item 1's string is "string 1" item 2's string is "string 2" and item 3's string is "string 3" If the user, in a textbox, enters the correct string for item 1 ("string 1") then the program will prompt you to enter item 2's string("string 2") @Ian

Comment: Sounds like homework :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object)().Select(Function(x) x >= x.ToString).ToList()
If items.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
    Dim nextIndex = items.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text) + 1
    If nextIndex < items.Count Then 'There is next item
        Dim nextItem = items(nextIndex).ToString()
        'Do something with your nextItem
    End If
End If
```

Basically, you try to get all texts in your `ListBox` by doing this:

```
Dim items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object)().Select(Function(x) x >= x.ToString).ToList()
```

Then you check if an input string is among the text in your ListBox:

```
If items.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
    .
    .
    .
End If
```

If it does, you get the index of the next item:

```
Dim nextIndex = items.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text) + 1
```

And if the index of the next item is not exceeding the `ListBox`'s number of of elements, you get the item in the next index:

```
If nextIndex < items.Count Then 'There is next item
    Dim nextItem = items(nextIndex).ToString()
    'Do something with your nextItem
End If
```

Your next string is in the `nextItem`, do something with it.

Or, without populating the whole item but still getting the same result, you could add additional `Where` LINQ clause (as suggested by [Codexer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797425/codexer)):

```
Dim item = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object)().Select(Function(x) x >= x.ToString).Where(Function(y) y = TextBox1.Text).FirstOrDefault()
If Not item Is Nothing Then
    Dim nextIndex = ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item) + 1
    If nextIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count Then 'There is next item
        Dim nextItem = ListBox1.Items(nextIndex)
        'Do something with your nextItem
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Good Linq solution although you could put a where condition and then you would only have what you would need for comparison. It would negate having records you don't need anyways...

Comment: Why the downvote? If the question is bad, the question should be downvoted and if the answer is bad, the answer should be downvoted. Why mix between the answer and the question? Is my answer not working? Not explaining enough? Not putting any effort to write? Please consider.

Comment: You still can. It will still be a list as you are only seeing if the text is in the list, there's no other comparison.

Comment: @Codexer you mean `IndexOf`, although the ListBox element is `Object` instead of `string`, can still find the right index when we insert a `string`?

Comment: Short answer is yes you can.

Comment: @Codexer OK, updated with your version, credit goes to you. :)

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful!